# Eval reference error

Tags: javascript, json

In javascript i am building up a string like this...

```
var txt = "{authenticationToken: 1, authenticated: 2, authenticationTokenExpiry: 3,sessionTimeoutMinutes: 4,userName: " + userName + "}";
```

This is later put through and eval statement like this...

```
var obj = eval('(' + txt + ')');
```

When this happenings I get a reference error saying the the value of the username variable is undefined.

Does anyone know the reason for this? Is it something simple that I am missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead of `eval`?

Comment: `eval ('(' + txt + ')')`? But anyway, where is `userName` defined?

Comment: This is to run on an old Blackberry phone where json.parse doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your variable isn't called `username` rather than `userName`?

Comment: Sorry I missed the + signs in the post but they are there in the real code.

Comment: @BenCameron - Consider using a [polyfill](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) so you can still use `JSON.parse` reliably.

Comment: Any reason you are creating the JSON and not just an object?

Comment: I'd make sure to validate that JSON first, otherwise you have a sizeable security hole using eval().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing quotes around the username variable:

```
var txt = "{authenticationToken: 1, authenticated: 2, authenticationTokenExpiry: 3,sessionTimeoutMinutes: 4,userName: '" + userName + "'}";
```

I assume you want to store the string value of the username in your userName variable. Since it wasn't quoted it was treating the value of username as a variable. So for example if username was "testValue123" it would of been `userName: testValue123` instead of `userName: 'testValue123'`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `eval()`, I would suggest using the [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method if jQuery is available:

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    var userName = 'me';

    var txt = '{"authenticationToken": 1, "authenticated": 2, "authenticationTokenExpiry": 3, "sessionTimeoutMinutes": 4, "userName": "' + userName + '"}';

    var obj = $.parseJSON(txt);
});
```

*NOTE: The string had to be modified to satisfy the requirement of a well-formed JSON string*

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WTC7k/

However, the reason that you're encountering the error that the value of `userName` is undefined is that you have to enclose the string in quotes to allow eval() to work properly:

```
var userName = 'me';

var txt = "{authenticationToken: 1, authenticated: 2, authenticationTokenExpiry: 3,sessionTimeoutMinutes: 4,userName: '" + userName + "'}"; 

var obj = eval('(' + txt + ')');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9rtgK/

Comment: Yes that would be ideal but sadly this code is for a Blackberry application on an older model. JSON.parse isn't available.